# How to use auto generate id for JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

Can somebody show me on how to use each id for JavaScript if my id in the code is auto incremental?
I want to make that each id for radio button that automatically generate based on value from database have their own function but I only know to use only the base id. The auto incremental id still I can't figure out on how to retrieve it.

Example for JavaScript (that will make id auto increase and button unchecked):

```
var list1 = document.getElementsByClassName("sos");
    for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    list1[i].setAttribute("id", "s" + i);
}

var list2 = document.getElementsByClassName("des");
for (var i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
    list2[i].setAttribute("id", "d" + i);
}

function test1(){
    if(document.getElementById('s').checked){
    document.getElementById('d').checked = false;
   }
}

function test2(){
if(document.getElementById('d').checked){
    document.getElementById('s').checked = false;
   }
}
```

This is my radio button:

```
<?php
   echo "<td align = 'center'>";
   echo"<input class ='sos' id='s' onchange='test();' type ='radio' name='x1'  required  value ='".$col['id_latihan']."'>";
   echo"</td>";



   echo "<td align = 'center'>";
   echo "<input class='des' id='d' onchange='test2();' type ='radio' name='x2'  required  value ='".$col['id_latihan']."'>";
   echo"</td></tr>";

?>
```

I want to make the radio button 1 if checked, radio button 2 will uncheck. But the function only work on first row only. the radio button that auto generate will not function because different id.

Comment: If those radio buttons should be mutually exclusive, then just give them all the same name. The id is not determining the native behaviour (without JavaScript); it is the name that does that. Just change your PHP to deal with it having the same name.

Comment: try to explain the feature that you need to do first, your code show nothing

Comment: Please show rendered HTML, not some PHP that we have to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

Better pass `this` within a function like this. Single function is enough. They will validate the id. Then find the opposite id and increment id number.

**Example code**

```
function test(that) {
    var f = that.id.match(/([a-z])(\d+)/)
    var op_id=f[1]=='s'? 'p':'s';

    if (that.checked) {
        document.getElementById(op_id+f[2]).checked = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="s1" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br>
<input id="p1" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br><br>
<input id="s2" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br>
<input id="p2" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br><br>
<input id="s3" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br>
<input id="p3" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br><br>
<input id="s4" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br>
<input id="p4" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br><br>
<input id="s5" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br>
<input id="p5" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)"><br>
```